# Linechart hover tooltip gives error - D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a line chart and there is a feature taken from: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html

It works fine in the example in the link, but for me it gives an error and nothing is shown on hover, even though everything else works well:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at SVGRectElement.mousemove (pen.js:366:28)
```

This is the code that is most likely causing the trouble:

```
function mousemove() { 
      var mouse_x = d3.mouse(this)[0]; // Finding mouse x position on rect
      var graph_x = xScale.invert(mouse_x); // 

      //var mouse_y = d3.mouse(this)[1]; // Finding mouse y position on rect
      //var graph_y = yScale.invert(mouse_y);
      //console.log(graph_x);

      var format = d3.time.format('%b %Y'); // Format hover date text to show three letter month and full year

      hoverDate.text(format(graph_x)); // scale mouse position to xScale date and format it to show month and year

      d3.select("#hover-line") // select hover-line and changing attributes to mouse position
          .attr("x1", mouse_x) 
          .attr("x2", mouse_x)
          .style("opacity", 1); // Making line visible

      // Legend tooltips // http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html

   var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]), /* d3.mouse(this)[0] returns the x position on the screen of the mouse. xScale.invert function is reversing the process that we use to map the domain (date) to range (position on screen). So it takes the position on the screen and converts it into an equivalent date! */
     i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1), // use our bisectDate function that we declared earlier to find the index of our data array that is close to the mouse cursor
      /*It takes our data array and the date corresponding to the position of or mouse cursor and returns the index number of the data array which has a date that is higher than the cursor position.*/
     d0 = data[i - 1],
     d1 = data[i],
      /*d0 is the combination of date and rating that is in the data array at the index to the left of the cursor and d1 is the combination of date and close that is in the data array at the index to the right of the cursor. In other words we now have two variables that know the value and date above and below the date that corresponds to the position of the cursor.*/
      d = x0 - d0.data > d1.data - x0 ? d1 : d0;
      /*The final line in this segment declares a new array d that is represents the date and close combination that is closest to the cursor. It is using the magic JavaScript short hand for an if statement that is essentially saying if the distance between the mouse cursor and the date and close combination on the left is greater than the distance between the mouse cursor and the date and close combination on the right then d is an array of the date and close on the right of the cursor (d1). Otherwise d is an array of the date and close on the left of the cursor (d0).*/

      //d is now the data row for the date closest to the mouse position

      focus.select("text").text(function(columnName){
         //because you didn't explictly set any data on the <text>
         //elements, each one inherits the data from the focus <g>

         return (d[columnName]);
      });
  };
```

I tried working around the issue, tried to find what is causing this, but so far I've had no luck. It would be great if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong that this is not working as in example.

The full code can be found here: http://codepen.io/kvyb/pen/ZeyRam?editors=0110

Comment: Looking at you pen, the simple answer is that d0 does not have a "data" property. It has a bunch of properties like "CSS_Site_A" etc.

Comment: I am trying to do as in example: http://bl.ocks.org/DStruths/9c042e3a6b66048b5bd4 . Not sure why it should be different from the way I adapted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the bisectDate function to return a meaningful value, the data must be sorted by date. Working pen below. Add this line right after you loop over the data and set the date field.

http://codepen.io/voam/pen/xdYNaM

```
  data = data.sort(function(a,b){ return a.date - b.date});
```

Answer (score 0):

Small typo. The field name is date, not data.

```
  d = x0 - d0.data > d1.data - x0 ? d1 : d0;
```

Should be

```
d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
```

Comment: unfortunately, this changes nothing.

Comment: I also noticed that your codepen links to both version 4 and version 3 of d3. The original example is from version 3. When I removed the link to version 4 it started to work.